# How to get http support in scapy

Tags: python, http, scapy, packet-sniffers

I am building a packet sniffer in python using scapy, now, I want to filter the http packets I am receiving and extract the url from them(Host + Path) but my program crashes with message: File "packet_sniffer.py", line 4, in 
    from scapy.layers.http import *
ImportError: No module named http

When typimg the scapy layers http import I can auto complete the http part so it seems like it does recognize it but when running it crashes.

I have tried other syntax in my code section such as using "scapy.http.HTTPRequest"
"scapy.layers.http.HTTPRequest"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.http import *




def sniff(interface):
scapy.sniff(iface=interface,
            store=False,
            prn=process_sniffed_packet,
            lfilter=lambda p: "POST" in str(p),
            filter="tcp port 80")


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    url = packet[scapy.layers.http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[scapy.layers.http.HTTPRequest].Path
    print(url)
```

Is there a problem with my module import or with the code?

** Note, I am using scapy 2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Scapy 2.4.3

Comment: I am using 2.4.3 version

Comment: This sounds technically impossible. Scapy 2.4.3 contains a module `scapy.layers.http`. Make sure `scapy.__version__` is 2.4.3. If you have several Python versions environments, make sure you installed Scapy with the correct manager (pip3 for instance...)

Answer (score -1):

How about using library `scapy_http` by replacing `from scapy.layers.http import *` with `from scapy_http import *`
like [this](https://medium.com/@777rip777/packet-sniffer-with-scapy-part-3-a895ce7e9cb)

Comment: No. Scapy http is obsolete: https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http